# How to trace the payload/body of REST calls send from the JAX-RS client in liberty?

Tags: jackson, jax-rs, cxf, websphere-liberty

How to configure WebSphere Liberty v17.x logging feature in order to see in the traces or logs the payload sent and received from a JAX-RS v2.0 call from WebSphere Liberty?
We tried many things including configuring the logging feature like this:

```
<logging traceSpecification="*=info
                            :com.ibm.websphere.jaxrs20.=all \
                            :com.ibm.ws.jaxrs20.=all \
                            :org.apache.cxf.*=all "/>
```

but we are still not able to see the payload send and received from JAX-RS calls.
We see lots of internal traces from WAS but no payload/body is visible
The payload/body is usually in JSon marshalled from `CXF` and `jackson`, the JAX_RS implementation bundled with liberty.
The Java mapping is done via JAXB annotations in java

Comment: Disappointing this isn't clearly documented anywhere. I had found the classes for the older, Wink-based JAX-RS 1.1 (http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21198363), but so far no luck on the CXF-based 2.0